# Adding Nodes To TreeView In For/ForEach Loop

Tags: c#, foreach, treeview

I've been trying to figure out but it is so complex, so I wanted to ask since I could not get an answer

```
CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        if(fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => StartListing(fbd.SelectedPath));
            SplittedPath = fbd.SelectedPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
            t.Start();              
            foreach(string s in SplittedPath)
            {
                if(treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(s);
                    i++;
                    treeView1.Nodes[i].ImageIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(s);
                    treeView1.Nodes[0].ImageIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my code.SplittedPath string is normally seems good.It has all splitted stuff but in ForEach loop, it seems like there are only 2 string.When I delete

```
if(treeView1.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(s);
                i++;
                treeView1.Nodes[i].ImageIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(s);
                treeView1.Nodes[0].ImageIndex = 0;
            }
```

This codes, it just works fine.When I add these to ForEach loop, it just does not add all SplittedPath strings.Any solution?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: If i choose "C:\Users\The Cowboy\Desktop\Socket Server", i want to add "C:" node, then add child node to it "Users", then child node again "The Cowboy"... I Think you understood what i mean.

Comment: Yes I understand now, you should update your question with what you said. About that you have an iterative and recursive solution to your problem, which part exactly are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't deal with the tree structure in your code, that's why it doesn't work. You only have 2 levels here.

If you want a tree presentation of your path you should do the following:

```
TreeNode n = null;
TreeNode parent = null;
foreach(string s in SplittedString)
{
    if (parent == null)
    {
        parent = new TreeNode(s);
        treeview1.Nodes.Add(parent);
        continue;
    }

    n = new TreeNode(s);
    parent.Nodes.Add(n);
    parent = n;
}
```

I don't say it's the best way to do it, but you have the general idea of an iterative solution.

You get a reference to the parent node, and as you go through your path, the parent changes to be the last node added. That way every `string s` will be at a different level of your tree structure.